# How to explode a pie chart into another pie chart using PHP/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, pie-chart

I’ve been trying to find a code that can explode a pie chart into another pie chart. This is because at the start when the pie chart loads it looks cramped up with so many entries. On the net I’m only able to find tutorials to do this using Excel. Can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out this lib, you can create dynamic and explorable pie charts with it (it š html5, javascript based).

Click and see yourself:

http://datavisualizationsoftwarelab.com/en/products/pie-chart/

Example of a Pie Chart:

[image: interactive pie chart]

Answer (score 1):

This will help you: [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

Comment: yeah went through that as well..nothing matches what I really want